# Setting null value for structtype column if the column doesn't exist

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct

I am working on a dataframe which has nested struct type columns. Data is being fetched from a folder which has N files. But these nested columns might not appear in all of these files. I want to create the dataframe in such a way that it includes all the columns and set a null value if the column is not present. I tried using the below code:

```
df = df.withColumn('fields_acceptance_criteria', 
          F.when(df.schema.simpleString().find("fields_acceptance_criteria$394") == -1, lit("null")) \
          .otherwise(col("fields.acceptance_criteria$394")))
```

But this is giving TypeError:

> condition should be a Column

Can someone suggest me some way to how I can achieve it.

Comment: does it not make non-existent values as null automatically? have you tried to enclose the condition's LHS and RHS in `lit()`?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about this. I am directly getting an analysis exception error: No such struct field acceptance_criteria$394 in description, documentKey, globalId, jira_align_feature_type$394, jira_align_status$394, name, priority2$394, send_to_implementation$394, state_worflow$394